# How to pass checkbox checked list to modal popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Am having a page with a button and a table

```
<input type="submit" value="Email" name="button" class="openDialog" data-dialog-id="Mail Dialog" data-dialog-title="Send Mail" data-url="<%: Url.Action("SendMail") %>" />    

<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>            
                <input type="checkbox"/>           
             <input type="hidden" class="textfield" id="video0_tags" name="video0_tags" />     
            </th>
            <th>
                FirstName
            </th>
            <th>
                LastName
            </th>
        </tr>
    <% foreach (var item in Model)
       { %>
        <tr>
            <td>            
                <div class="taglist">
                <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<%: item.ProfileId %>" /> 
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)%>
            </td>
    <% } %>
    </table>
</form>
```

And in my controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SendMail(string video0_tags)
    {            
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendMail(int[] check,Profile profile, mail email)
    {

            foreach (var item in check)
            {
                var dbprofile = db.Profile.Single(p => p.ProfileId == item);
                string Emailid = dbprofile.EmailId;
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("xxxx@gmail.com");
                msg.From = fromAddress;
                msg.To.Add(Emailid);
                msg.Subject = email.Subject;
                msg.Body = email.Body;
                msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxx@gmail.com", "password");
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Send(msg);
            }
        return RedirectToAction("Profiles", "profile");
    }
```

**Problem**

My problem is that am unable to pass the checkbox checked values to the get actionresult of popup. This is send email to multiple members based on checkbox checked items.

Can any one help me..... Please

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the checkbox is a boolean input.

Is would be better if you would store the profile id in a hidden input field

And by the way don't forget to wrap your table in a form.

```
<form>
   <input type="submit" .../> 
   <table> ... </table>
</form>
```

Comment: public ActionResult SendMail(string myhidden) but its taken null...no values are been passes

Comment: have you wrapped you table in a form?

Comment: yes i have stored my profile id in hidden field. and also wrapped my table in form... but there is no change

Comment: could you update your question with the code that you are currently having in you view and also your action

Comment: Here my button shows a pop up. if i remove pop and keeps simple button then am able to pass the value..